# Why can't I craft a chest?

Tags: terraria

According to the [Terraria Wiki](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Chest) I should be able to craft a chest with 8 wood, and 1 iron bar or 2 lead bars. I have more than 8 wood, and an iron bar. The wiki also states that a standard crafting station is sufficient, which I also have (and standing right on top of when I attempt) but a standard chest is still not craftable. What am I missing? The wiki, under "Craftable Chests" doesn't mention any other prerequisites for making one, and I'd like to store my crap before exploring this apparently dangerous world.

Thanks.

Edit: Screenshot added. I am near a work bench, and have the required materials in my inventory (1 iron bar + 8 wood). 
[image]

Comment: We would be better off with a screenshot, with your inventory open, of a situation in which you think you should be able to make a chest, but can't.

Comment: Which "standard crafting station" do you have?

Comment: Added a screenshot -- sorry -- the work bench is the crafting station I'm using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The (2) on the wiki is for both the iron bar and lead bar. You need 2 iron bars to make a chest. You can check this in game by bringing an iron bar to the guide and he will show you the recipe.

[image]

Comment: Ah, I see.. I would have expected something like "Iron Bar (2) or Lead Bar (2)". I see what you mean. I finally got more iron and after making a 2nd bar, was able to craft the chest. Thanks for the information. (I didn't realize asking the guide was a thing too, that's helpful)